# If the form has an error. How do I create an alert with error? [PHP, XHTML]

Tags: php, mysql, html, xhtml

What I want to do, but i dont know how to make:

I have my form:
   - Condition: If an error occurs then receive a message with a red alert.

[image: alert type]

The form is with the POST method and redirected to another file that makes the necessary consultations.

```
    <?php   
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

    if ($nickname && $email && $amount) {
        if ($captcha == 19) {       
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO donations(nickname, email, amount) VALUES('$nickname', '$email', '$amount') ");

            echo "<script>
            alert('Thanks you!');
            window.location.href='http://example.com';
        </script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>
            alert('Incorrect captcha!');
            window.location.href='http://example.com/';
        </script>";
    }
    }else{
        echo "<script>
        alert('Please, complete all fields!');
        window.location.href='http://example.com';
    </script>";
    }


    mysql_close();



    ?>
```

So: I wish the messages appear on the same page where the form is made, making it appear a message like the image. with their respective colors, either, error or success.

Simple example: https://gyazo.com/56457e697f2d4459a71d04d3198889e7
But with: [Complete all fields] [Send satisfactorily]

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's going on with the yahoo login form is that, when the user click on the `Next` button, the page does not do a full `form` post to the "consultation page" (page does not reload). What it does is that the page itself is using Javascript, and made an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to the "consultation page", with the details provided, and gets only the result from the "consultation page".

This technique is called "[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))", and it's around for more than 2 decades. Take a look here for the very simple tutorial provided by w3school: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/.

---

`XMLHttpRequest` may be too simple for the real world usage. So plenty Javascript frameworks out there have provided wrappers for developers to use this technique without the hassles of browser compatibilities. Such wrappers are like the famous [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), can do a lot of cool things that you can leverage with.

For your problem, you will need to do something like this:

- When user click on a button to submit a form, instead of submitting the form, you call an Javascript function to post to your second "page"
- The page that's responsible to it should receive all the parameters you have submitted in the call as per normal. If you do a `post`, you should get it via `$_POST`.
- The page then is responsible in checking the data, do the task, and send a response back to the callee.
- The original page that does the post, will receive the response, and you can act accordingly, such as show an alert, or do whatever related actions on the page itself.

---

*Footnote:*

*The world is changing very fast. Modern Javascript development is pretty much more sophisticated than just this ajax calls. This is just one simple technique that we have been using in the past for more than decades.*

Comment: I feel the delay. Thanks for your reply.